# Clone items in a list by index

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array

```
np.array([[1,4,3,5,2],
          [3,2,5,2,3],
          [5,2,4,2,1]])
```

and I want to clone items by their indexes. For example, I have an index of

```
np.array([[1,4], 
          [2,4],
          [1,4]])
```

These correspond to the positions of the items at each row. e.g. the first [1,4] are the indexes for 4, 2 in the first row.

I want in the end returning a new numpy array giving initial array and the index array.

```
np.array([[1,4,4,3,5,2,2],
          [3,2,5,5,2,3,3],
          [5,2,2,4,2,1,1]])
```

The effect is the selected column values are repeated once. Any way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand. Could you explain what you mean by "the positions of the items at each row"?

Comment: Your problem is difficult, because once you duplicate the index `1`, the index `4` refers to a different value than it did when you started.  Do you want to duplicate the new value, or the original?

Comment: the second array (`[1,4], [2,4], [1,4]`) adds a repetition in the first one. e.g. in the first row: [1,4,3,5,2], and [1,4], adds [1, 4, **4**, 3, 5, 2, **2**] (at index 1 and 4 in the initial array).

Comment: For this task it might be easiest to work with a list of lists.  The action for each row is sufficiently different that it will be difficult to treat it as a 'whole-array' problem.  In a list the offset created by duplication can be handled by iterating from the end.  Another option is to treat this as a 1d array.  The 2d layout only complicates the insertion task.

Answer (score 2):

I commented that this could be viewed as a 1d problem.  There's nothing 2d about it, except that you are adding 2 values per row, so you end up with a 2d array.  The other key idea is that `np.repeats` lets us repeat selected elements several times.

```
In [70]: arr =np.array([[1,4,3,5,2],
    ...:           [3,2,5,2,3],
    ...:           [5,2,4,2,1]])
    ...:           
In [71]: idx = np.array([[1,4], 
    ...:           [2,4],
    ...:           [1,4]])
    ...:
```

Make an array of 'repeat' counts - start with 1 for everything, and add 1 for the elements we want to dupicate:

```
In [72]: repeats = np.ones_like(arr)
In [73]: repeats
Out[73]: 
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
In [74]: for i,j in enumerate(idx):
    ...:     repeats[i,j] += 1
    ...:     
In [75]: repeats
Out[75]: 
array([[1, 2, 1, 1, 2],
       [1, 1, 2, 1, 2],
       [1, 2, 1, 1, 2]])
```

Now just apply `repeat` to the flattened arrays, and reshape:

```
In [76]: np.repeat(arr.ravel(),repeats.ravel())
Out[76]: array([1, 4, 4, 3, 5, 2, 2, 3, 2, 5, 5, 2, 3, 3, 5, 2, 2, 4, 2, 1, 1])
In [77]: _.reshape(3,-1)
Out[77]: 
array([[1, 4, 4, 3, 5, 2, 2],
       [3, 2, 5, 5, 2, 3, 3],
       [5, 2, 2, 4, 2, 1, 1]])
```

I may add a list solution, once I work that out.

---

a row by row `np.insert` solution (fleshing out the concept suggested by @f5r5e5d):

Test with one row:

```
In [81]: row=arr[0]
In [82]: i=idx[0]
In [83]: np.insert(row,i,row[i])
Out[83]: array([1, 4, 4, 3, 5, 2, 2])
```

Now apply iteratively to all rows.  The list of arrays can then be turned back into an array:

```
In [84]: [np.insert(row,i,row[i]) for i,row in zip(idx,arr)]
Out[84]: 
[array([1, 4, 4, 3, 5, 2, 2]),
 array([3, 2, 5, 5, 2, 3, 3]),
 array([5, 2, 2, 4, 2, 1, 1])]
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know np.insert can insert multiple elements at a time.

Answer (score 1):

`np.insert` may help

```
a = np.array([[1,4,3,5,2],
          [3,2,5,2,3],
          [5,2,4,2,1]])

i = np.array([[1,4], 
          [2,4],
          [1,4]])


np.insert(a[0], 4, a[0,4])

Out[177]: array([1, 4, 3, 5, 2, 2])
```

as mentioned, `np.insert` can do more than one element at a time from a one dimensional obj

```
np.insert(a[0], i[0], a[0,i[0]])

Out[187]: array([1, 4, 4, 3, 5, 2, 2])
```

Comment: You can insert several values at a time.  I expanded on your idea.

Comment: thank you both. my initial reaction is to use np.insert. However, I didn't know we can insert multiple elements at a time. Therefore, I was confused by the fact that after inserting one element, the index of the second item in the new expanded matrix will be changed by 1 or not, depending on whether its index value is larger or smaller than that of first element in the original matrix. A for loop can be written to compare different indexes and determine its updated index in the expanded matrix, however, this is not elegant.